# Propagating GET parameters in a select

Tags: jsf-2, get, richfaces

I have a select box in which the user can choose the skin of choice:

```
<h:form style="float: right;">
  <h:outputText value="Skin:&#160;" />
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{skinBean.skin}" id="skin-selector" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="DEFAULT" itemLabel="Default" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="classic" itemLabel="Classic" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="blueSky" itemLabel="Blue Sky" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="deepMarine" itemLabel="Deep Marine" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="emeraldTown" itemLabel="Emerald Town" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="japanCherry" itemLabel="Japan Cherry" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="ruby" itemLabel="Ruby" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="wine" itemLabel="Wine" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

This element is placed in a template and is seen on every page.

Question:

How do you **propagate the current page's GET parameters** so that skin selection will not end up in the same page without any GET parameters (which the code above currently does)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this i can see is to write a javascript or jQuery function which gets the curent URL and append the Skin to it. I have rewriten your code.

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{skinBean.skin}" id="skin-selector" onchange="changeSkin(this)">

   function changeSkin(selectObject){
        var url = location.href;
        var value = selectObject.options[selectObject.selectedIndex].value;
        if(url.indexOf("?") > 0 ){
            var skinQIndex=url.indexOf("?skin");
            var skinAIndex=url.indexOf("&skin");
            if(skinQIndex > 0 ){
                if(url.indexOf("&",skinQIndex+1)>0){
                     var str = url.substring(0,skinQIndex+1) + "skin="+value + url.substring(url.indexOf("&",skinQIndex));
                     url =str;
                    }else{
                        url = url.substring(0,skinQIndex+1)+ "skin="+value; 
                    }
            }else if(skinAIndex >0){
                if(url.indexOf("&",skinAIndex+1)>0){
                     var str = url.substring(0,skinAIndex+1)+ "skin="+value + url.substring(url.indexOf("&",skinAIndex+1)) ;
                      url =str;
                    }else{

                        url = url.substring(0,skinAIndex+1)+ "skin="+value; 
                    }
            }else{
                url = url + "&skin="+value; 
                }                           
        }else{
            url = url + "?skin="+value;
        }
        window.location.href = url;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, did you fix the issue, if yes please let me know the approach you followed. Thanks naveen